# module "QtMultimedia" is not installed on android

Tags: c++, qt, qml

It can run successfully under the **Windows** system, but on the **Android** system, an error message

> module "QtMultimedia" is not installed

appears with a white screen. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Using QtMultimedia alone will not result in an error, but when placed in a project, an error message will appear: "module" QtMultimedia "is not installed"

Comment: a little too many variables was left out unknown? What version of Qt? Did you mean a QML module? Do you have `QT+=multimedia` in project? How do you deploy to android (at some point Creator doesn't have an option to deploy qml import paths, `androiddeployqt ` does)